# How do I covert a number to a date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, where-clause

I have a field named `SECURED` that has dates listed as `123120`, `040320`  which is actually `12/31/20` or `4/03/20`.
I was able to convert the date in the `SELECT` area with:

```
SELECT LEFT(SECURED, 2) + '/' + replace(replace(SECURED, LEFT(SECURED, 2), ''), 
       RIGHT(SECURED, 2), '') + '/' + RIGHT(SECURED, 2) as 'Modified SECURED as Date' 
WHERE CONVERT(date, SECURED, 101) 
      BETWEEN CONVERT(date, getdate() - 30, 101) 
          AND CONVERT(date, getdate(), 101)
```

How can I pull in information from the `SECURED` column with a date of 30 days ago?

It doesn't work and still sees a date as a number.

Comment: SQL itself is a standard, but vendors tend to implement it differently.  For the best support, you should tell us what Database Management System (DBMS) you are using. For example, MySQL, Oracle, MSSQL, etc.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18

Comment: Your first query doesn't [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) the number to a [`date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), just to a string that might look more like a typical display of a date. Aside: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is not a database, but it can connect to a variety of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datefromparts()` to convert your string to a date:

```
datefromparts(
    concat('20', substring(secured, 5, 2)),
    substring(secured, 1, 2),
    substring(secured, 3, 2)
)
```

Then you can check it against a given interval:

```
datefromparts(
    concat('20', substring(secured, 5, 2)),
    substring(secured, 1, 2),
    substring(secured, 3, 2)
) between dateadd(day -30, cast(getdate() as date)) and cast(getdate() as date)
```

Comment: The only issue is that the OP suggests `secured` is a number/integer, so substring won't work without a cast.

Comment: @h0r53: I speculated on that, but they give the example of `'040320'`: the leading `0` makes it look like a string rather than a number.

Answer (score 1):

If `secured` is a string, you can do a little manipulation and a simple `cast()`:

```
select convert(date, concat('20', right(secured, 2), left(secured, 4))
```

You might find it convenient to actually create a *computed column* so this is always available:

```
alter table t add secured_date as (try_convert(date, concat('20', right(secured, 2), left(secured, 4))
```

You can even persist the column and create an index, so your queries are more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

#### There're many ways to convert a 6 digits `INT` to `DATE`:

---

You can do a convertion using `LTRIM` and `CAST` like this:

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(LTRIM(123120),2) + LEFT(LTRIM(123120),4) AS DATE)
```

Using `LTRIM` with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(040320), 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(LTRIM(040320), 1, 4) AS DATE)
```

---

Using `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CAST((RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), 123120),2) + 
              LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), 123120),4)) AS DATE)
```

Or using `CONVERT` with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), 040320), 5, 2) + 
            SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), 040320), 1, 4) AS DATE)
```

---

Using `STR`:

```
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(STR(123120, 6) ,2) + LEFT(STR(123120, 6) ,4) AS DATE)
```

Or using `STR` with `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(STR(040320, 6), 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(STR(040320, 6), 1, 4) AS DATE)
```

---

> This casting will format the date as expected but your dates need be
> in format `mmddyy`

> Standard EUA (style 10) `DATE` format (`mm-dd-yy`) without century (`yy`)

---

### Edit after comments:

- What's the table name of this query?
- What's the `SECURED` field datatype? `INT`? `VARCHAR`?
- You need convert a date and compare between last 30 days and today?
- The query below resolve your problem? (change `TABLE_NAME` to your table name)

---

```
SELECT LEFT(SECURED, 2) + '/' + replace(replace(SECURED, LEFT(SECURED, 2), ''), 
       RIGHT(SECURED, 2), '') + '/' + RIGHT(SECURED, 2) as 'Modified SECURED as Date'
       FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE CAST(RIGHT(LTRIM(SECURED), 2) + LEFT(LTRIM(SECURED), 4) AS DATE)
      BETWEEN GETDATE() - 30 AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: The 123120, 040320 where just examples. I do not know know how many items are actually out there. I want to pull these items in. I am not concerned about the SELECT date but the WHERE. I need to pull in all items where the secured field has a "date" within the last 30 days. Hence me trying to do                                                                     
WHERE
CONVERT(date,SECURED,101) between CONVERT(date,getdate()-30,101) and CONVERT(date,getdate(),101)

Comment: @Octomaki I edited the answer, this resolve your problem?

Comment: No, I still get Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.I would need all items with a date within the past 30 days

Comment: Man, only with these information it's complicated to help you. Please put the log message and improve your question to someone can help you. I think your're not being clear about your specificly problem.